# Visual Studio 2010's generate model from database gives error message when trying to connect to DB with MySQL ADO.NET drivers, how to fix?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, connection-string, entity-model

I am trying to generate my ADO.NET entity model from my MySQL database using the official Connector/Net 6.4.3 ADO.NET drivers from MySQL. However, after I type in my DB-info, and click next (Test Connection reports successful connection), I get the following error message from Visual Studio:

An error occurred while connecting to the database. The database might be unavailable. An exception of type 'System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException' occurred. The error message is: 'The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string'.

The inner exception caught was of type 'System.FormatException', with this error message: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. There is a bug with the ADO.NET connector that makes localized Windows versions report that error message. The way to fix it is to change region settings (in windows control panel) to US and English (United States). I could then update model from database without errors.